# Cast NSURL ** to CFURLRef *

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

How can I compile the following code using ARC?

```
int main() {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL new];
    NSURL * __strong *urlPointer = &url;
    CFURLRef *cfPointer = (__bridge CFURLRef *)urlPointer;
    geturl(cfPointer);
    NSLog(@"Got URL: %@", url);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Incompatible types casting 'NSURL *__strong *' to 'CFURLRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFURL **') with a __bridge cast
```

I know that `CFURLRef` is already a pointer, so `CFURLRef *` is a pointer to a pointer, however the external function I'm using (`geturl`), is requiring a `CFURLRef *` as parameter.
I have no control over the function, so I can't change that.

How can I cast the `urlPointer` to a `CFURLRef *` pointer?

Comment: If you mean doing `geturl(urlPointer)`, then no as I get the error `Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFURLRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFURL **') is disallowed with ARC`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of what you're doing is just convoluted pointer calisthenics. Why not just do this:

```
CFURLRef cfPointer = NULL;
geturl(&cfPointer);
NSURL *url = (__bridge NSURL *)cfPointer;
NSLog(@"Got URL: %@", url);
```